# observable collection with multiple observers with different filter criterion

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I want to develop an observablecollection which can have many observers each with it's own Linq based filter criterion.

I understand that I could easily create a filtered observable collection for each observer manually. But I am more interested in an elegant design approach to keep this abstracted from the observers.

filter criterion for each observer will be loaded from a configuration based on object properties.  Then the observer should subscribe to the primary collection for changes in objects based on given filter criterion.

I want to write this implementation in a generic way so it can work for any object and it's collection.

Addition to this, I want to use the same filter for notifying the changes in the the collection items itself. So the subscriber are subscribing to the changes in the elements and not the collection itself. subscriber gets notified of the change in the element only if the subscription filter is satisfied.

So for example: 
I have a collection of order objects in Order List. Subscribers subscribe to my collection class based on given LINQ based criterion. Whenever any object in the collection is updated, only the subscribers which satisfy the filter criterion are notified.

Comment: I suggest you get to work. Just create new generic class that implement IEnumerable and INotifyCollectonChanged and pass your "data source" collection together with your filter to constructor, rest is just attaching handlers and deciding what and when will you pass data.

Comment: I am thinking on similar lines. Trying to come up with a wrapper class to implement my requirements. I am going to edit my question to add some additional question on the collection items

Comment: I would start with a DataTable as the Source of the data.  The filter on columns.  You can get the names of the columns easily and the contents using Linq.  The datatables can also be filled easily from the Database adapter.

Comment: *Any suggestions* -- Sorry, too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you also check https://reactiveui.net/ ?

Comment: not yet! will check it out. thanks. to note, my example doesn't have a UI, it's a server based process.

Comment: @Alok - You seem to have a fairly clear idea on what your code should look like - at least from the consumption POV. You should write as much as you can and let us know which parts you are struggling with. We can then help fill the gaps. We are not here to be a code writing service, so don't rely on us to get this important first step done. Do it yourself so that we can answer with a minimum of effort. This is why you don't have an answer yet.

Comment: Why the system.reactive tag?

Comment: @Enigmativity understood. I was thinking more on the lines of what design pattern should be used to approach this problem. I thought this must have been encountered many times by developers. In any case, I will get stuff working and if I am stuck at any point, will reach out here. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Sentinel I was wondering if observable/reactive framework could be used to implement the solution. Anyways, i am going to close this question for now.

Comment: @Alok you might also want to look into serializing expression trees